# code conversion from itext 2 to itext 5.5

Tags: itext

I am generating PDF using itext 2 and below is the code

```
String xhtml = toXHTML(xml).replaceAll("<br>", "<br/>");
      ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
      renderer.setDocumentFromString(xhtml);
      renderer.layout();
      File temp = File.createTempFile("test", ".pdf");
      temp.deleteOnExit();

      OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(temp);

      renderer.createPDF(os);
      os.close();
```

But, when I place itextpdf-5.5 jar.I am getting below error

```
 The type com.lowagie.text.DocumentException cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

I know some of the methods are deprecated. I tried using Document class but, it did n't work.

Do I need to find alternatives for createPDF method in the new api or is there any way we can make jar not to refer 'lowagie' which is deprecated. Any help on this is so much appreciated

Comment: Doesn't the 5.5 use different packages for Classes?

Comment: I was expecting new jar, not to refer deprecated ones but, error says it is referring to 'lowagie' which is deprecated

Comment: See the answer you have to fix all the imports from com.lowagie to com.itextpdf and most of it should work, depends on the itext version and methods ur using.

Comment: If you want to upgrade, why would you upgrade from an obsolete version (2) to a version that is "end of life" (5)? Why not use iText 7 and pdfHTML? See http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iText 2 packages were starting with `com.lowagie`, while iText 5 packages are starting with `com.itextpdf`. Replacing JAR won't work in such place. You will have to replace all the imports.

If you're using 3rd party dependecy that uses iText this error means you have to use version 2. There was a major change in license with version 5 of iText so the two are not interchangeable.

Comment: In my imports I had only package import org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer; In my imports, I am not referring to 'lowagie'

Comment: Than you cannot replace iText 2 with iText 5. Your dependency requires iText 2. Most projects use iText 2 because of license changes in version 5.

Comment: Basically it will not work with iText 5. You need to use iText version 2.

Comment: This is the correct answer. (I am the Lowagie you (should) know from the `com.lowagie` classes.)

Comment: @Kiran just to make it clear: `ITextRenderer` is **not** an iText class, it is a third party class *using* iText.